# Have Sri Vaishnava acharyas endorsed the concept of "tamasa purana"s?

Tags: puranas, sri-vaishnava

apparently Koorattazhwan uses the concept of "tamasa purana" for polemics against Saivas.  how about Ramanuja, vedanta desika et al.?

Comment: The concept of Tamasa Purana differ from Acharya to Acharya... for  eg. Yamunacharya in Agama Pramnaya quotes a quote from Matsya Purana which says 'Puranas praising Agni and Shiva are Tamasic'... while Sripati (Lingayat Acharys) quote various quotes which say 'Vaishnava Puranas are Tamasic.' 

Comment: But Agni is the most pure among all the Panchabhutas and is also a Brahmin, then what's the link between praising Agni and being Tamsik? @Tezz